# JavaFX8 tree table remove disclosure node indentation

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, treetable

The disclosure node is placed in a separate column which for root items contain that arrow and for child items - some data. Currently there's an indentation between arrow and data(see image below).
[image: disclosure node indentation]

How can I remove that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I looked high and low for a solution to this my self and finally found it by looking at the source for the skin for the `TreeTableRow`. Apparently there is a css property called `-fx-indent` that will do what you need.

This is how I achieved a similar result to what I believe you are trying to do:

```
.tree-table-row-cell{
    -fx-indent: -20;
}
```

Obviously you need to figure out a better value than `-20` but that did the trick in my proof of concept.

I hope this helps.